# "The native class hasn't been loading" error with my bindings

Tags: ios, binding, xamarin.ios, gpuimage

I'm trying to create bindings for [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/framework/Source) project, but none of binded classes is working.
For example, GPUImageView:

In ObjC it's declared like this ([header in git](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/framework/Source/GPUImageView.h)):

```
@interface GPUImageView : UIView <GPUImageInput>
//then some fields, properties and methods I'm not interested in
```

So, my ApiDefinition.cs looks like this:

```
namespace GPUImage
{
    [BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
    [Model]
    interface GPUImageInput {
    }

    [BaseType (typeof(UIView))]
    interface GPUImageView : GPUImageInput {
        [Export ("initWithFrame:")]
        IntPtr Constructor(RectangleF frame);
    }
}
```

LinkWithAttributes:

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("libGPUImage.a", LinkTarget.Simulator | LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.ArmV7s, ForceLoad = true, Frameworks = "CoreMedia CoreVideo OpenGLES QuartzCore AVFoundation UIKit Foundation")]
```

It builds ok and creates dll. But when I try to use it in my project like this:

```
var iv = new GPUImageView (new RectangleF (0, 0, 100, 100));
```

Exception throwed:

> Could not create an native instance of the type 'GPUImage.GPUImageView': the native class hasn't been loaded.
>   It is possible to ignore this condition by setting Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.

[Stacktrace](http://pastie.org/7160314)

After `MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure == false` `iv` was created, but unusable (e.g. `AddSubview(iv)` show nothing).

I suppose there is something wrong with GPUImage.a file, but I don't know how to test it in any way.

[Here is 7z](http://rghost.net/44867526) with 2 projects in it: TryingBindings -- bindings themselves; TryingGPUImage -- bindings in use;

Thanks in advance.

P.S. [Here is the link to this post on xamarin forums.](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2749/the-native-class-hasnt-been-loading-error-with-my-bindings)

Comment: Can you share the header files to the objective-c library? I don't see them in your 7z file.

Comment: @jonathanpeppers, https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/framework/Source/GPUImageView.h

Comment: Does the empty constructor work for you? I don't see any `init` methods in here.

Comment: No, same exception. Same exception also occurs on 5 of 5 other constructors I've tried to bind. Btw, can you see any way to check if GPUImage.a is valid in some sense?

Comment: Ok, wait. Remove `GPUImageInput` entirely and see what happens.

Comment: Nothing changed. What should change? My ApiDefinition is now just 4 lines: GPUImageView declaration (without GPUImageInput inheritance ofc).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27223/discussion-between-folex-and-jonathanpeppers)

Comment: Don't edit the question to say SOLVED. Answer it yourself and accept the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Rolf Bjarne Kvinge

> There are two problems:
>
> 1) The file with the LinkWith attribute (libGPUImage.linkwith.cs) is
>   not compiled. Just right-click the TryingBindings project, Add, Add
>   files and select it.
>
> 2) The native library does not contain code for i386 (simulator), only
>   arm (device). If you're building the native library yourself you can
>   either create a universal library that contain code for all the
>   architectures, or you can use several native libraries, each
>   supporting a different set of architectures, and just have a LinkWith attribute for each native library.

[Bug 11497](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11497)

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Added the sample projects here https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11497 could you please take a look & point me in right direction? Thanks