# Getting could not create an native instance of the type 'JumioNetverifyBinding.NetverifyConfiguration' the native class hasn't been loaded exception

Tags: objective-c, xamarin, binding, xamarin.ios

I am trying to bind Jumio Natverify library in Xamarin iOS project by creating Objective c library project.

I have crated ApiDefination.cs and Struct.cs file data using sharpie tool. But when I am trying on run it I am getting Could not create an native instance of the type 'JumioNetverifyBinding.NetverifyConfiguration': the native class hasn't been loaded. exception.

ApiDefinition class - [ApiDefinition.cs](https://github.com/divyesh08/JumioBindingLib/wiki/ApiDefinition.cs)

Struct class - [Struct.cs](https://github.com/divyesh08/JumioBindingLib/wiki/Struct.cs)

**Called NetverifyViewController from iOS Binding project:**

```cs
using Foundation;
using JumioNetverifyBinding;
using System;
using UIKit;

namespace JumioNetverifyDemo
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        NetverifyViewController netverifyViewController;

        public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            StartNetverifyButton.TouchUpInside += startNetverify;
        }

        public void CreateNetverifyController()
        {
            NetverifyConfiguration config = new NetverifyConfiguration();
            config.ApiToken = "My_token_key";
            config.ApiSecret = "Secrate_key";
            config.DataCenter = JumioDataCenter.Eu;
            
            config.Delegate = new NetverifyViewControllerDelegateHandler(this);
            this.netverifyViewController = new NetverifyViewController(config);
        }

        public void startNetverify(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.CreateNetverifyController();
            if (this.netverifyViewController != null)
            {
                this.PresentViewController(netverifyViewController, true, null);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Netverify Mobile SDK : NetverifyViewController is null");
            }
        }

        public void DisplayAlertAsync(string title = "Alert", string message = "")
        {
            var okAlertController = UIAlertController.Create(title, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            okAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
            PresentViewController(okAlertController, true, null);
        }

        public class NetverifyViewControllerDelegateHandler : NetverifyViewControllerDelegate
        {
            private ViewController _viewController;

            public NetverifyViewControllerDelegateHandler(ViewController viewController)
            {
                _viewController = viewController;
            }

            public override void DidCancelWithError(NetverifyViewController netverifyViewController, NetverifyError error, string scanReference, string accountId)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NetverifyViewController did finish initializing, error:" + error.Message);
                _viewController.DisplayAlertAsync("Error : " + error.Message);
            }

            public override void DidFinishWithDocumentData(NetverifyViewController netverifyViewController, NetverifyDocumentData documentData, string scanReference, string accountId, bool authenticationResult)
            {
                _viewController.DisplayAlertAsync("Scan Reference : " + scanReference);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am looking for anyway to handle this exception and make this library work, if anyone have idea about this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. Make sure that the native library (.a file) is built to support the architecture you are deploying to , `x86_64 , i386` for 32 and 64 bit simulators  , `armv7 and arm64` for 32 bit and 64 bit devices .  2. Check `linkwith.cs` file to ensure it is included in your sample project .Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/15759249/8187800 and https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/282919/#Comment_282919.

Comment: Yes it does support all architecture.

Comment: Do you make sure the `linkwith.cs` is being compiled?

Comment: yes, it does get compiled automatically.

Comment: Could you provide the library(.a or .framework)  file so that we can test it ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply but the file is not accessible there .

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i8gbr28idl8x6os/AAAa9kbJLg8cEjtZT34ntWoja?dl=0 check this link

Comment: Thanks for sharing the file I will create a test based on it and will get you back if something update .